# Tags for US OTC securities

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm wondering which tags I should use for questions about US over-the-counter (OTC) stocks for retail investors. The popular tags are: [pink-sheets](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pink-sheets) and [penny-stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-stocks). However, there are questions about OTC securities that don't necessarily fit into "pink-sheets" or "penny-stocks". Examples of such questions are:

- Questions about OTCBB
- Questions about OTCQX and OTCQB: [pink-sheets](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pink-sheets) seems to imply "OTC Pink" only, excluding OTCQX, OTCQB.

Questions:

- Do OTCQX, OTCQB questions belong under the "pink-sheets" tag?

  - Suggestion: Edit the tag description to explicitly allow OTCQX, OTCQB, and OTC Pink questions under the more colloquial name of "pink sheets".
- Do OTCBB questions belong under the "pink-sheets" tag?

  - Suggestion: Create an "otcbb" tag.
- Should there be a generic tag for US retail OTC markets?

  - Some time ago, I created [over-the-counter](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/over-the-counter) for my questions, but I don't think the name is proper. "over-the-counter" has many meanings, whereas what I wanted was a tag specifically about "OTCBB, OTCQX, OTCQB, and OTC Pink". The problem with "otc-stocks", "otc-securities", "otc-markets" is that they are not US-specific, and not specifically about "OTCBB, OTCQX, OTCQB, and OTC Pink". I thought of "us-retail-otc-securities", which is precise, but too long.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIC, there have not been nor will there ever be enough questions to warrant breaking the "over-the-counter" tag  into individual  tags for OTCBB, OTCQX, OTCQB, and OTC Pink.  The poster can specify which type his question is about.